# How to copy raw data to ctypes.Structure from Python C extension?

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

Is it possible to get the value of pointer to raw data of `ctypes.Structure` instance in Python C extension? I would like to access and copy data from/to the instance of this class without bothering the interpreter by importing and using `ctypes.memmove` or `ctypes.addressof`. In other words, does `ctypes` provide any C API which I can use directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that ctypes exposes a C API.

This is how it's done in >= 2.7: http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module

ctypes source tagged at 2.7.1: http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Modules/_ctypes/

I don't see anywhere in the source where an API capsule is built.  You'll have to use the ctypes Python interface via the Python C API instead.